Adding values of Indicators
I want to count how many times some indicators give signals in last 50 candles, means if Some indicators give Buy 1st time, then 1 and after some time again buy then add one more time so total is 2, up to last 10 candles, if its giving sale then -1 so net = 1.
I tried to use if condition satisfied then add 1, but it's not giving correct result as it only doing sum for current candle,
Correct Results = if condition satisfy 5 times longCondition in last 50 bars then longCondition value = 5 and if it satisfy 3 times short condition then shortCondition value = 3.
Currently, it's only giving value of the last candle, ignoring previous values. If the last candle don't satisfy longCondition & shortCondition value, then it's giving 0, ignoring past values.
  long_count = 0.5
  short_count = 0.5

i1 = longCondition ? 1: shortCondition  ? -1: 0
   

if i1 == 1
    long_count += 1
else if i1 == -1
    short_count += 1


To limit the last 50 candles, you can use last_bar_index
last50Bars = bar_index > last_bar_index - 50

and for the counter, a switch
var long_count  = 0
var short_count = 0
switch
    last50Bars and longCondition  => long_count  += 1
    last50Bars and shortCondition => short_count -= 1


Hello Gu5tavo71 - Thanks a lot for your help in this regard.  i have done this by using "For Loop"
